# Crystal Reports 2013 - Running Total with Weekly Data

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm a beginner with Crystal Reports.  I'm using Crystal Reports 2013, and I've made a report with a structure like:

```
<Person>
  <date>
    <sale amount>
    <sale amount>
    <sale amount>
```

So I'm grouping by Person, and then by date.  (And sorting by time).  Now, Crystal Reports decided to also group my data by the week.  That's perfectly okay by me.  But how do I calculate the weekly total sales?

More specifically, I don't know "why/how" the report is automatically grouping by week.

So here's what I've tried:  I created a running total field for the sale field.  But:

- If I set it to group on the date field, it groups daily. (Fair enough, except it's inconvenient)
- If I set it to group on the person field, it keeps a running total of all sales through that week.

Here's the thing though:  I'd like the report to group the data into weeks by default, and keep a weekly total.  But I'd also like to include the option to group the data into months, and have the running total know that it should be a monthly running total.  So far, I've only seen a way to keep a daily running total.

So, I guess specific my question is **what group is Crystal Reports grouping by when it automatically groups by week?**  If this is the wrong question, any other advice to achieving my goal would be helpful, though.

Thanks!

Comment: Its your running total that's probably doing it. have you tried using the sales amount field straight away and then insert Summation of it on the group footers? without using running totals

Comment: @aMazing: Yes, that was right.  I think I might have been reading the report wrong.  But I tried it with `Insert > Summary` and it looks okay.  I will experiment a little to see if the old way worked.  In any case, thank you.  You'll get the answer credit if you turn it into one. :-)

Comment: @aMazing: definitely was not reading the report incorrectly.  Your advice worked and was very helpful.  Thanks!  I will take a look at how the sum is implemented in the field explorer so I never make that mistake again.

Comment: Thats good. I have added it as answer for you to accept. Give me some points ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its your running total that's probably doing it. 
Have you tried using the sales amount field straight away and then insert Summation of the field on the group footers? YOu may not need to use running totals.